# Call the button click event based on name property

Tags: jquery

I have one **HTML button** like,

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnName" class="btnclass" value="Click Me" />
```

I want to call **jQuery button click** event based on `id` property means,
we use the code like,

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){ 
    ////////
});
```

as well as call **button click** event based on `class` property means,
we use the code like,

```
$(".btnclass").click(function(){
    /////////
});
```

and my question is, I want to call the **button click** event based on `name` property means, How to do this?

Comment: Actually, to select by class you should prepend a '.' (period) in front of the selector. jQuery by default uses CSS selectors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You  can use the name property for that particular element. For example to set a border of 2px around an input element with name `xyz`, you can use;

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name = 'xyz']").css("border","2px solid red");
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/LnFcv/2/)

Comment: +1 -> The other answers were right too, but you provided a demo which is always helpful.

Answer (score 15):

```
$('element[name="element_name"]').click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

in your case:

```
$('input[name="btnName"]').click(function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use normal CSS selectors to select an element by name using jquery. Like this:

```
Button Code
<button type="button" name="mybutton">Click Me!</button>

Selector & Event Bind Code
$("button[name='mybutton']").click(function() {});
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the jquery attribute selector. You can read more here:

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

In your case it should be:

```
$('input[name="btnName"]')
```