# how can use jquery show/hide text box from name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my textbox names is
exm: `<input name="packageconfigoption[2]" size="20" value="" type="text">`
packageconfigoption[X], X is a number, and not have ID
how can i show and hide input from this name?
i used this code, but not work, have syntax error

```
    $('input[packageconfigoption[6]]').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Exm1") {
        $('input[packageconfigoption[13]]').hide();
    } else {
        $('input[packageconfigoption[8]]').show();
    }
    });
```

i want if packageconfigoption[8] value changed, packageconfigoption[x] hide or show

Comment: "not work" is virtually never a good enough explanation of a problem, here. describe what happens, or should but does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696604/jquery-call-the-jquery-button-click-event-based-on-name-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this using [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('input[name="packageconfigoption[6]"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Exm1") {
        $('input[name="packageconfigoption[13]"]').hide();
    } else {
        $('input[name="packageconfigoption[8]"]').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct selectors that you use in your query would be `input[name="packageconfigoption[6]"]`, etc., not what you currently have.

In other words the attribute name `name` is what goes inside the brackets, and then it's set to the attribute value via an `=` symbol:

```
element[attribute="attribute_value"]
```

Right now what you have is a query looking for an `input` element with an attribute of `packageconfigoption[6]`, not an attribute of `name` with a value equal to `packageconfigoption[6]`.